# Can not run tests with Jest on NestJS

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I am trying to create and e2e test for my GraphQL endpoints. After a bit of struggling to let Jest find the tests, I now see that Jest tries to run the tests as JavaScript, not TypeScript. Here is an error output:

```
SyntaxError: /server/__tests__/users.e2e-spec.ts: Unexpected token, expected ";" (9:10)

   7 |
   8 | describe('AppController (e2e)', () => {
>  9 |    let app: INestApplication
     |           ^
  10 |    let apolloClient: ApolloServerTestClient
  11 |
  12 |    beforeEach(async () => {

  at Parser.raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/location.js:41:63)
  at Parser.unexpected (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:150:16)
  at Parser.semicolon (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/util.js:123:40)
  at Parser.parseVarStatement (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:703:10)
  at Parser.parseStatementContent (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:216:21)
  at Parser.parseStatement (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:146:17)
  at Parser.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:865:25)
  at Parser.parseBlockBody (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:841:10)
  at Parser.parseBlock (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/statement.js:818:10)
  at Parser.parseFunctionBody (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/expression.js:1964:24)
```

Here is the test script from package.json:

```
"test:e2e": "jest --config ./tests/jest-e2e.json"
```

And the Jest config file:

```
module.exports = {
   roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
   transform: {
      '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
   },
   testRegex: '(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.tsx?$',
   moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],
}
```

What am I doing wrong? According to NestJS docs, the tests should run out of the box.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following the directions on the ts-jest page solved my problem.

Putting it here incase someone needs it:

Create a jest config:

```
yarn ts-jest config:init
```

If you use baseUrl in tsconfig.json, modify the config as below:

```
module.exports = {
   preset: 'ts-jest',
   testEnvironment: 'node',
   modulePaths: ['<rootDir>/src'],
}
```

I wish NestJS docs included this. It could save me time.

Answer (score 2):

With configured paths on tsconfig.json
Create jest.config.js on root project folder

```
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils')
const { compilerOptions } = require('./tsconfig')
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths),
  modulePaths: [
    '<rootDir>'
  ],
}
```